# mountain climbing problem

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, maxima-minima

The wikipedia article on the [mountain climbing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_climbing_problem) mentions two things which I am unable to reproduce on a number of test mountains I drew:

- that *both* of the climbers may occassionally need to go down the mountain
- that for a mountain with *n* peaks and valleys the number of turns can be as large as quadratic in *n*.

Perhaps it doesn't help that the article's illustration is a rather mundane mountain that exhibits none of these two properties. Apparently I am missing something. Can someone provide the drawing of a mountain that would satisfy either one or both of the above conditions? Also, why would a mountain with areas of constant height complicate matters?

Comment: What does "as large as quadratic in $n$" mean in this context?

Comment: If either climber is 'going down' the mountain in the simple sense that their altitude is decreasing, then necessarily BOTH of the climbers must be 'going down'. So I'm guessing they mean something more along the lines of 'going BACK down' the mountain; they are walking away from the global peak (and potentially also decreasing in altitude, maybe????). And so we want to find a set of ridges that requires both to be going 'BACK down the mountain' simultaneously at some point in order to reach the global peak.

Comment: @chasbrown I believe Wikipedia means "walking away from the highest peak" as you say (the other interpretation being trivial) and that's what I am failing to reproduce.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidian n to the power of 2. I don't see how that's possible either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, here's an example where climbers $A$ and $A'$ start at their respectively marked locations; and in order for both to reach the glorious icy peak at $P$, at some point $A$ must backtrack segment $DC$ while $A'$ simultaneously backtracks segment $F'E'$:

[image]

For both climbers, they are simultaneously going away from the peak of Mount $P$. I'm still trying to think of an example where they are also both  *decreasing* their altitude as they move away from the peak; but perhaps this is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it shows backtracking and I can now believe (given there's backtracking) that the number of turns can be quadratic n. However I still don't see how flat regions cause problems and why it is important that the formulation of the problem explicitly states that "there are no intervals of constant height".

Comment: As I read the article, the interval constraint is because otherwise weird, but still continuous, functions like $x \cdot sin(1/x)$ (well, not that function exactly but functions like it that meet the other rules) would then cause problems ("then the first climber may be forced to go back and forth infinitely many times, and thus can never reach the top").

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Chas Brown's answer — Here's an SVG animation of the two climbers solving Chas's example. (I tried to upload this animation to Wikimedia Commons and thence to Wikipedia, but it turns out Wikipedia doesn't really support animated SVGs, so it's not particularly viewable there.)

[image]